# Getting logs out of wireshark pcap files

Tags: wireshark, logging, pcap

I converted the wireshark pcap file to a windows txt file using TShark's command tshark -V -r {file} 
Is the data contained inside the windows txt file converted from the wireshark's pcap file the log data? Or is there a better way to get logs out of the wireshark pcap files??

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what the purpose of the log file is.  If you intend to hand it to, for example, [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) (and, no, [I didn't pick Splunk at random](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/10234/getting-logs-out-from-the-wiresharks-capture-pcap-file) :-)), you might want to ask  about this on [the Splunk Q&A site](http://splunk-base.splunk.com/) rather than on a generic Q&A site or a Wireshark Q&A site, as most of the issues are probably Splunk issues and you're more likely to find people familiar with Splunk there.